# The matrix associated with a linear map for general vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

From Serge Lang's Introduction to Linear Algebra, page 152:

> Let $L:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear map [$V$ is a vector space]. Suppose that there exists a
> basis $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ and numbers $c_1,...,c_n$ such that
> $Lv_i=c_iv_i$ for $i=1,...,n$. Then with respect to this basis, the
> matrix of $L$ is the diagonal matrix
>
> $\left[\begin{matrix}  c_1 & 0 & ... & 0 \\  0 & c_2 & ... & 0 \\   . & . & &. \\ 0 & 0 & ... & c_n \end{matrix}\right]$

From what he wrote earlier, if an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ is associated with linear map $L: R^n\rightarrow R^m$, then $L(X)=AX$, where $X\in R^n$. In the quotation above he's saying that $L(v_i)=c_iv_i$, but how would one multiply a matrix by $v_i$, when $v_i$ can be anything? In order to do the multiplication, $v_i$ must be a vector in $n$-space. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: In your last four lines you tell us how Lang defined the matrix of a linear transformation on the space $R^n$. But what is relevant here is how Lang defined the matrix of a linear transformation on a general vector space $V$.

Answer (score 1):

$v_i$ is a vector, because it is an element of $V$.

---

You know that $\{v_1,\dots, v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$. Well, a *basis* for a vector space is always a subset of a vector space. So, you know that $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}\subseteq V$, which in turn means that, for every $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, you have $v_i\in V$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that as $v_i\in V$ is a vector in a vector space, in particular we can multiply by scalars from the base field, so $c_i v_i\in V$. The statement $L(v_i)=c_i v_i$ says that $L$ acts on $v_i$ as multiplication by a scalar.

If $\lbrace v_1,\dots, v_n\rbrace$ is a basis, every element $w\in V$ can be written as
$w = a_1 v_1 + \dots + a_n v_n$
for $a_i \in V$. Then, as we know how $L$ treats the basis vectors, and that it is linear, we see that
$L(w) = a_1 L(v_1) +\dots + a_n L(v_n) = c_1 a_1 v_1 + \dots + c_n a_n v_n.$
Compare this to
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
c_1 & 0 & \dots & 0\\
0 & c_2 & \dots & 0 \\
. & . & . & . \\
0 & 0 & \dots & c_n
\end{pmatrix}w
\end{align}
when $w$ is written in the coordinates of the $v_i$ basis, and you will see they are equal.